# how to show SSAS value side by side in Excel 2010 Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot, ssas

I think this question is more of a excel related one but here is what i am doing, i have a SSAS cube which i access using Excel 2010.

I want to see the Values/measures side by side , if the dimensions are same across the row for a selected periods. i have tired all the Pivot Options which i know but no use, please help me. I have attached a example below. Thank you.

**Example:** 
[image]
I want to see the data like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "Design" tab for your pivot table tools and change the report layout. You can choose a tabular form, outline form or compact form. Repeat all item labels is an option that you will want to select.

I'd probably select "Repeat all item labels" then change it to a tabular form.